# Edit all attribute error messages dynamicly

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, attributes, asp.net-mvc-4, metadata

I have made my own translation system, and i need to translate all of the validation errors produced by validation attributes, i have already done so with the DisplayNames like this:

```
public class MyCustomDataAnnotationModelProvider : DataAnnotationsModelMetadataProvider
{
    protected override ModelMetadata CreateMetadata(IEnumerable<Attribute> attributes, Type containerType, Func<object> modelAccessor, Type modelType, string propertyName)
    {
        var data = base.CreateMetadata(attributes, containerType, modelAccessor, modelType, propertyName);

        if (data.DisplayName != null)
            data.DisplayName = Translator.TranslateOnce(data.DisplayName);

        return data;
    }
}
```

And that translates all of the Display attributes::

```
[Required(ErrorMessage="message"), Display(Name="Language"), StringLength(10)]
public string LanguageName { get; set; }
```

So basicly i want to do the exact same thing with the validation error, but i can't figure out how to iterate through them. 
There is this thing called data.GetValidators() but it requires the ControllerContext, which i can't find.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could achieve this by creating an attribute derived from ActionFilterAttribute and modifying the ModelState collection in the `OnResultExecuting` method. Then apply this attribute globally by using `System.Web.Mvc.GlobalFilters` collection.

To modify the ModelState:

```
public override void OnResultExecuting(ResultExecutingContext filterContext)
{
    foreach (var s in filterContext.Controller.ViewData.ModelState.Values)
    {
        for (var i = s.Errors.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            var e = s.Errors[i];
            if (e.Exception != null && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(e.ErrorMessage))
                s.Errors.Add(new ModelError(Translate(e.Exception), Translate(e.ErrorMessage)));
            else if (e.Exception != null)
                s.Errors.Add(new ModelError(Translate(e.Exception)));
            else 
                s.Errors.Add(new ModelError(Translate(e.ErrorMessage)));

            s.Errors.RemoveAt(i);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: But then i would need to put that attribute on every single property right?

Comment: no, you would add the action filter globally and then it will be called after every action is executed (note that the validators will return the default messages so in the action code they will not yet be translated).

Comment: How do i edit the values in ModelState, the values ive found where Read Only.

Comment: Ok, and will this also send the translated error messagees down and into in to the HTML Attributes? for onobtrusive validation?

Comment: yes, the filter would execute before the view engine is called and thus the HTML helpers will see only the translated texts

Comment: Would you like my left arm? I have been strouggleing with this all day, could you please provide a code example on how to replace the ModelState, and edit the error messages?

Comment: sorry about that, see the new code that now should work (for a change I actually tested it).

Comment: Ha' Cool, Thank you so much! It works great, but it still doesnt translate the unobtrosive validation attribute values, but i won't give up yet.